# Java doesn't execute all the code in the main method

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to implement a simple insertion sort algorithm whose job is to sort a given `ArrayList` into decreasing order.

Here is all the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(reader.nextInt());
        }

        sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toString(list.get(i)) + " ");
        }
    }

    private static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            int key = list.get(i);

            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && list.get(j) < key) {
                list.set(j + 1, list.get(j));
                j--;
            }

            list.set(j + 1, key);
        }
    }
}
```

However, sometimes the `System.out.print` method in the `for` loop doesn't get always executed for all the elements in the list. Here are some samples of input and output:

```
// Input:
31
41
59
26
41
58
^C
// Output:
59 58 41 

// Input:
5
2
4
6
1
3
^C
// Output:
6 5
```

I can't understand why this is happening. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works as expected on my machine, using your code without any changes... Try adding `System.out.println();` at the end of your main method.

Comment: Are you on the command line or in an IDE console?

Comment: I'm using the command line - Java 8 on a 64bit Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Are you using `Ctrl+C`? I guess you should use `Ctrl+Z` - `Ctrl+C` terminates the program and may be that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you! `Ctrl+Z` solved the issue!

Comment: Working fine...as programmed..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the "try with resources" language construct.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(reader.nextInt());
        }

        sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toString(list.get(i)) + " ");
        }

    } /* catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
    } */
}
```

Another point is: You exit the program with "STRG+c" (I see "^C" at the end). Maybe the inputstream is not able to flush properly. You should introduce an exit condition rather than using OS depended shortcuts.